# My image is not opening in open cv, tried a lots of solution but still the same problem

Tags: c++, image, opencv

i have tried out almost every format of writing path of that specific image in my code(/,//), even tried out by putting the image into project folder with some respective changes. but still there is an assertion error(without if condition).I tried my best to solve this but still the image not opening. I am a newbie using OpenCV c++ . Please help me I am tired with this error.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{

    Mat img = imread("test.png");
    if (!img.data)
    {
        std::cout << "Image not loaded";
        return -1;
    }
    imshow("Display Image", img);
    waitKey(5000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try getting and printing the current working directory so you know where it is looking for your image... https://www.delftstack.com/howto/cpp/get-current-directory-cpp/

Comment: Please edit question and paste the error message you get.

Comment: Can also try `std::system("pwd");`